# Automatically Subscribe all users to Super Admin Google Account

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need one super admin account to be able to view all Google calendars for all users in the organization.

To do this manually I would do the following:

Repeat for all users:

1. Using my super admin account go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar
2. Click on subscribe calendar and enter the email of the user

I want to automate this process using Google APIs.

1. Fetch all users in the organization
2. If I have not subscribed already then subscribe

Is it possible to do this via Google APIs? I was unable to find documentation on subscribe in Google Calendar API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add calendars to your super admin account from other users by using the method [CalendarList: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) as this will add a specified calendar to your calendar list.

To get the calendar id required to insert this calendar into your calendar list you could use [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) and [impersonating](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/domain#accessing_domain_calendars_as_an_app) each user on your organization to then iterate over this list of calendars to get the `id`. I recommend doing this process using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

1. Create a service account.
2. Iterate over each user on your organization.
3. On each user make a `CalendarList: list` call and iterate over each calendar of this list.
4. For each calendar use `CalendarList: insert` to insert this calendar in the super admin (or any other user) account.